# Manipulating dynamically created SVG elements

Tags: jquery, ajax, svg

I'm trying to be able to "drag" SVG elements (using Raphael) loaded from a database around a canvas using AJAX. I can load them and display them from the DB fine, but when I want to add event handlers to each individual one, I can't seem to get it right.

I tried using .on() after loading all elements from the DB, when the DOM is ready:

```
$('circle').on("mousedown", function(event) {
        ox = event.screenX;
        oy = event.screenY;
        event.target.attr({opacity: .5});
        dragging = true;
    });
```

But this never seems to get called.

I can add events during the creation of the circles, but then only the last element added actually moves--but only if the mouse is within the X,Y of the other loaded circles:

```
var data = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "map.php",
    data: "loadMap=1",
    success: function(text) {
        var item = text.split(";");
        for (x in item)
        {
            if (item[x].length > 0)
            {
                var str = item[x].split(",");
                if (str[0] == "node")
                {
                    var c = svg.circle(str[1], str[2], 10);
                    c.attr("id", str[3]);
                    c.attr("fill", "black");
                    c.attr("stroke", "none");

                    c.mousedown(function(event) {
                        ox = event.screenX;
                        oy = event.screenY;
                        c.attr({opacity: .5});
                        dragging = true;
                    });

                    c.mousemove(function(event) {
                    if (dragging) {
                        c.translate(event.screenX - ox, event.screenY - oy);
                        ox = event.screenX;
                        oy = event.screenY;
                        }
                    });

                    c.mouseup(function(Event) {
                        dragging = false;
                        c.attr({opacity: 1});
                    });

                }
                else if (str[0] == "room")
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong, or better yet, what is the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the amount of circles it might be a bad idea adding an event listener to each of them. A more robust solution would be adding the event to the svg element

```
$("#svgelement").on("mousedown", "circle", function(event){
        target = this;
        ox = event.screenX;
        oy = event.screenY;
        target.setAttribute('opacity', 0.5)
        dragging = true;
});

$("#svgelement").on("mousemove", function(event){
  if (dragging) {
      if(target) target.setAttribute('transform', 'translate('+ event.screenX - ox +','+  event.screenY - oy +')');
      ox = event.screenX;
      oy = event.screenY;
  }
});

//attached to the window, otherwise you might drag
//all the way out of the svg and release there.
$(window).on("mouseup", function(Event) {
   dragging = false;
   target.setAttribute('opacity', 1)
   target = false;
});
```

Another benefit is that you don't require to load this as callback on ajax success, so you can discard sync problems.

Comment: This appears to be working well (and CPU usage is down...), but I cannot move objects anymore. .translate isn't a function of event.target, it's a Raphael.element function. How can I cast/get it in that form? Paper.getElementByPoint() is the direction I'm going right now, but I'm working on calulating all the required offsets.

Comment: Oh, I forgot you were using Raphael. I don't know how to get the Raphael object from a Dom element, but doing this in pure javascript is quite easy, answer updated.

Comment: Thanks. The transform attribute seems to be the ticket.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error could be that you refer to `c` from inside the mouse event handlers you are attaching to circles.

Then each event handler refers to the object that `c` refers to, i.e. the last object. `event` carries a **target** member, and you should use that instead.

I'm using jQuerySVG, and the event' member I'm using is **currentTarget**, see if is available for you (I think so)

Comment: This was an issue, but it seems I cannot .transform() or .translate() or change attributes and have them actually move the objects. I believe the problem is casting (or whatever it is in JS) an event.target to an Raphael SVG element.